# ¿Como soluciono el error 40 de sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

espero se encuentren todos muy bien, tengo un problema con el sql_server, eh construido una aplicacion web en asp.net pero a la iniciar sesion en esta, me arroja el gran error 40 de sql_server
Estoy trabajando localmente, en mi ordenador.
[image: como ven aqui, este es el error, perdon si no se vee mucho mas grande. en el sql server managemente studio si ingreso normalmente, solo es cuando ejecuto la app en el navegador]

[image: aqui pueden ver la configuracion del sql server, el browser aparece como "detenido", pero este no se inicia manualmente, y pues ya no se que se hace]
[image: y asi tengo los protocolos]
[image: aqui esta la manera en como hago la conexion]

Espero por favor de su gran sabiduria, es para una prueba para el lunes y estoy estudiando, pero, ya me detuve de golpe con esto...

muchisimas gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor edita tu pregunta (haz clic en [edit]) y cambia las imagenes por el código en formato texto. Las preguntas que incluyen sólo imagenes del código no son bienvenidas por la comunidad, lo cual puede ocasionar su cierre. Puedes leer [este post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu) al respecto. Saludos

Comment: Coloca bien la cadena de conexion del servidor, no le agregues singo de punto ". ", si estas local no deberias tener problemas.

Comment: efectivamente era eso, la cadena de conexion, me estaba guiando de un tutorial, pero eso no funciono... ya lo solucione. muchisimas gracias.